# How to make a binary file similar to xlsx, docx, pptx with java?

Tags: java

I don't really what is the umbrella term for these files 'xlsx, docx, pptx', so let's call it 'binary files'.
And I want to make a database file use the structure/technic of these 'binary file'. But I really don't know where to begin, what keywords should I research. I hope you guy could give me some advice about how to create a 'binary file' in java.

(BTW, I just want to use pure java)

Comment: it depends on what kind of data you want to store in that file. they are all different depending on the data model. and I wouldn't use microsoft office files as examples of good file formats :)

Comment: I want to store String and Int in the file, which can be query like a database.

Comment: the simplest method is writing a CSV file but then you have to do all the read / process / write back operations yourself. or you can use java database libraries such as HyperSQL which will do all that work for you. you can query it as a database (because it is one) but have it store the data in a single file - http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html